# getting "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener)' on a null object reference"

Tags: java, android, firebase, nullpointerexception, firebase-authentication

I was trying to make firebase authentication but for some reason this button is giving a NullPointerException, I checked the button name and I cant find why it is throwing such error

the code and the Logcat are included below

Logcat:

```
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.anan.login.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Main.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText mEmail,mPassword;
    Button mButton;
    TextView Login;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.Email);
        mPassword = findViewById((R.id.Password));
        //mButton = findViewById(R.id.button);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class));
            finish();



        }

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String Email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //Register user in Firebase
                fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Register Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class));

                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Register failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Email"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.52"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Password"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.52"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.405" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="79dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

...............................................................................................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind view to your activity before accessing its widget

Add below line just after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` inside onCreate(..) method

```
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Answer (score 1):

You never assigned a value to `mButton`.  You have an assignment commented out:

```
        //mButton = findViewById(R.id.button);
```

If you don't assign it a value which is an actual View in your view hierarchy, it's going to retain the default value of null.

Also, I'm noticing that you never inflated your layout.  You simply don't have any views to work with at all.

Answer (score 0):

1. You did not specify the layout in your onCreate method so your main activity has no layout to inflate
2. You did not assign a value to mButton in your onCreate method so it is authomatically assigned null.

Replace your onCreate code with the following:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);                   //Specify your layout
     mEmail = findViewById(R.id.Email);
     mPassword = findViewById((R.id.Password));
     mButton = findViewById(R.id.button);             //Assign a value to mButton from your layout
     progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
     fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

     if (fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class));
        finish();
        }


    }
```